# Git: how to find branchs where one of the last 3 commit is mine

Tags: git

I try to get the branchs from a git repo where one of the X last commit is one of mine. It's a bit tricky, I've tried with --author but failed :(

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

`git log -n 3 --all --decorate --author=Petr`

`--all` should do the trick.

Comment: Adding `--decorate` will also output the branch name

Comment: Thanks @MorKadosh . Adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, bu does not give me clearly the branch list :(

Here I found another way, that need more code but give me a clear list of branchs:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" | \
while read entry
do
log=`git log $entry~3..$entry --author="$(git config user.name)" --format="oneline"`
if [ ! -z "$log" -a "$log" != " " ]; then
        echo $entry
fi
done
```